# Numpy Indexing of multidimensional array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

I have an array `x` whose shape is `(308, 308, 308)`. I have an array of integer indices `v` of shape `(10, 308, 308, 3)`. I would like to index `x` so as to create a matrix `y` of shape `(10, 308, 308)` whose `(i, j, k)`-entry is `x[tuple(v[i, j, k])]`. Is there a fast way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: `y = x[(*v.transpose(3,0,1,2),)]`

Comment: Thank you. I had to wrap the transpose axes into a tuple but otherwise this worked fantastically.